# Display db content in another acitivity by clicking on item in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

So I have this problem, my listview is populated from Sqlite DB and I can click on any item in the listview. When I click on an item I want to display, in a new activity these "name, surname, age etc" details but these should be retrieved from my database.
Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use onItemClickListener method in your listview. When user clicks an item pass the item into next activity and in next activity retrieve data based on the item click. This tutorial will help you to get a good idea.

[Import and Use External Database in Android.](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html)

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Set an onItemClickListener for your ListView and when an item is clicked, you could either:

1. Place into a Bundle the details you want to be given to the Activity intent

Or

2. Place as an extra/bundle to the Activity intent the ID of the item you retrieved, then retrieve the details you want from the DB using the given ID inside of the next Activity